# Install ubuntu on Seagate BarraCuda 1Tb

Tags: ubuntu, hard-drive, partitioning

I'm having a hard time installing Ubuntu in a **brand new** Seagate BarraCuda Compute HDD. I'm installing via Ubuntu LiveUSB. I install ubuntu many times before with other hard drives. I wonder what makes Seagate so different from other experiences.

Hardware:

- Intel i5-2500k
- Zotac H67 ITX board

When formating using GParted:

I get this warning message:

```
    e2label: Input/output error while trying to open /dev/sda3
    Couldn't find valid filesystem superblock.
    
    Couldn't find valid filesystem superblock.
    
    dumpe2fs 1.45.5 (07-Jan-2020)
    dumpe2fs: Input/output error while trying to open /dev/sda3
    
    Unable to read the contents of this file system!
    Because of this some operations may be unavailable.
    The cause might be a missing software package.
    The following list of software packages is required for ext4 file system support:  e2fsprogs v1.41+.
```

I also get: `input/output error during read on /dev/sda`

I have e2fsprogs. I wonder what I might be missing.

Does anyone manage to install ubuntu on a Seagate BarraCuda 1Tb as the primary hard drive?
There is any reason why is so difficult to format BarraCuda on Ubuntu?

Additional information: Partition table type: GPT
Partitions are:

```
 Fat32,
 linux-swap,
 ext4 <-- occurs warning above
```

When running the installation without making my own partitions. Ubuntu will create the required ones but it gets stuck on :`Creating ext4 file system for / in partition #2 of SCSI3(0,0,0) (sda)...`

Tried with different HDD data cables and same result.

SMART Data Report on a new Disk in Ubuntu.

[image]

Comment: What's it formatted as? MBR/GUID(GPT) FAT, NTFS, etc etc...

Comment: I wonder if only drives beyond 2tb can actually work. https://www.seagate.com/au/en/support/kb/linux-os-support-for-disk-drives-beyond-22-terabytes-tb-218575en/

Comment: Things to try/check: replace HDD data cable. Verify that the drive has (enough) power.

Comment: @Hannu, I already tried with different cables. I had one Toshiba hdd running before with the same configuration. Weird but I wonder if seagate hdd < 2tb actually works on linux.

Comment: @ePascoal The S.M.A.R.T content you posted is insufficient - please [perform](https://superuser.com/a/1466640/529800) a short and long S.M.A.R.T test on the drive [`sda3`] and once the long test completes, please post the output of `smartctl -a /dev/sda3` into your question _(remove serial from the output)_. Ideally, you should [burn-in](https://www.truenas.com/community/resources/hard-drive-burn-in-testing.92/) a drive before using it, and if the S.M.A.R.T output doesn't show an issue and you still can't figure it out, you may want to give that a try.

Answer (score 0):

This was the answer I got from Seagate:

'We do not recommend Seagate hard drive connect to Ubuntu/Linux System because our hard drive only tested on Windows and Mac environment. We truly apologize that we unable to provide support further assistance / software support / troubleshooting steps'

Comment: No point listening to crap from "official support specialist" whatsoever; often they are just cheap labor know nothing about computer at all (their job is just copying and pasting base on "keywords"). With situation like this, just have the disk returned/replaced while you can. I doubt that it can work in Windows/macOS either.

Comment: Well if is like you say it really shows how good seagate is. It has been a nightmare for me without any relevant help from the stores/brand