# My Laptop has suddenly slowed down a couple weeks ago, and it has became slower gradually since then. it boots slow, shuts down slow, load files slow

Tags: hard-drive, performance

I thought problem is Windows, so I installed fedora (dual boot), but didn't solve the problem. about a year a go, I had exactly the same fedora (33), it was all good and smooth, but now, it's sort of slow. you think is it hard disk? though my hard is kind of new, just worked for about a year. a Kingstone hybrid (256GB SSD, 1TB HDD) which came with my laptop.

```
$ sudo smartctl -a /dev/sda
smartctl 7.2 2021-01-17 r5171 [x86_64-linux-5.12.7- 
200.fc33.x86_64] (local build)
Copyright (C) 2002-20, Bruce Allen, Christian Franke, www.smartmontools.org

=== START OF INFORMATION SECTION ===
Model Family:     Seagate FireCuda 2.5
Device Model:     ST1000LX015-1U7172
Serial Number:    ZDEJ1WKC
LU WWN Device Id: 5 000c50 0c3ef78e3
Firmware Version: SDM1
User Capacity:    1,000,204,886,016 bytes [1.00 TB]
Sector Sizes:     512 bytes logical, 4096 bytes physical
Rotation Rate:    5400 rpm
Form Factor:      2.5 inches
Device is:        In smartctl database [for details use: -P show]
ATA Version is:   ACS-3 T13/2161-D revision 3b
SATA Version is:  SATA 3.1, 6.0 Gb/s (current: 6.0 Gb/s)
Local Time is:    Wed Jun  9 20:46:21 2021 +0430
SMART support is: Available - device has SMART capability.
SMART support is: Enabled

=== START OF READ SMART DATA SECTION ===
SMART overall-health self-assessment test result: PASSED

General SMART Values:
Offline data collection status:  (0x00) Offline data collection activity
                    was never started.
                    Auto Offline Data Collection: Disabled.
Self-test execution status:      (   0) The previous self-test routine completed
                    without error or no self-test has ever 
                    been run.
Total time to complete Offline 
data collection:        (    0) seconds.
Offline data collection
capabilities:            (0x71) SMART execute Offline immediate.
                    No Auto Offline data collection support.
                    Suspend Offline collection upon new
                    command.
                    No Offline surface scan supported.
                    Self-test supported.
                    Conveyance Self-test supported.
                    Selective Self-test supported.
SMART capabilities:            (0x0003) Saves SMART data before entering
                    power-saving mode.
                    Supports SMART auto save timer.
Error logging capability:        (0x01) Error logging supported.
                    General Purpose Logging supported.
Short self-test routine 
recommended polling time:    (   1) minutes.
Extended self-test routine
recommended polling time:    ( 169) minutes.
Conveyance self-test routine
recommended polling time:    (   2) minutes.
SCT capabilities:          (0x3035) SCT Status supported.
                    SCT Feature Control supported.
                    SCT Data Table supported.

SMART Attributes Data Structure revision number: 10
Vendor Specific SMART Attributes with Thresholds:
ID# ATTRIBUTE_NAME          FLAG     VALUE WORST THRESH TYPE      UPDATED  WHEN_FAILED RAW_VALUE
  1 Raw_Read_Error_Rate     0x000f   082   064   006    Pre-fail  Always       -       173805718
  3 Spin_Up_Time            0x0003   099   099   000    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
  4 Start_Stop_Count        0x0032   096   096   020    Old_age   Always       -       4273
  5 Reallocated_Sector_Ct   0x0033   100   100   036    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
  7 Seek_Error_Rate         0x000f   076   060   045    Pre-fail  Always       -       37693246
  9 Power_On_Hours          0x0032   096   096   000    Old_age   Always       -       3675 (107 8 0)
 10 Spin_Retry_Count        0x0013   100   100   097    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
 12 Power_Cycle_Count       0x0032   100   100   020    Old_age   Always       -       721
184 End-to-End_Error        0x0032   100   100   099    Old_age   Always       -       0
187 Reported_Uncorrect      0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
188 Command_Timeout         0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       1
189 High_Fly_Writes         0x003a   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
190 Airflow_Temperature_Cel 0x0022   064   051   040    Old_age   Always       -       36 (Min/Max 27/42)
191 G-Sense_Error_Rate      0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       10
192 Power-Off_Retract_Count 0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       27
193 Load_Cycle_Count        0x0032   096   096   000    Old_age   Always       -       9431
194 Temperature_Celsius     0x0022   036   049   000    Old_age   Always       -       36 (0 18 0 0 0)
197 Current_Pending_Sector  0x0012   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
198 Offline_Uncorrectable   0x0010   100   100   000    Old_age   Offline      -       0
199 UDMA_CRC_Error_Count    0x003e   200   200   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
240 Head_Flying_Hours       0x0000   100   253   000    Old_age   Offline      -       4054h+51m+59.709s
241 Total_LBAs_Written      0x0000   100   253   000    Old_age   Offline      -       6871526994
242 Total_LBAs_Read         0x0000   100   253   000    Old_age   Offline      -       23827975406
254 Free_Fall_Sensor        0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0

SMART Error Log Version: 1
No Errors Logged

SMART Self-test log structure revision number 1
Num  Test_Description    Status                  Remaining  LifeTime(hours)  LBA_of_first_error
# 1  Short offline       Completed without error       00%      3675         -
# 2  Extended offline    Completed without error       00%      3605         -
# 3  Extended offline    Completed without error       00%      3548         -

SMART Selective self-test log data structure revision number 1
 SPAN  MIN_LBA  MAX_LBA  CURRENT_TEST_STATUS
    1        0        0  Not_testing
    2        0        0  Not_testing
    3        0        0  Not_testing
    4        0        0  Not_testing
    5        0        0  Not_testing
Selective self-test flags (0x0):
  After scanning selected spans, do NOT read-scan remainder of disk.
  If Selective self-test is pending on power-up, resume after 0 minute 
  delay.
```

.

```
[~]$ sudo smartctl -a /dev/sdb
smartctl 7.2 2021-01-17 r5171 [x86_64-linux-5.12.7-200.fc33.x86_64] (local build)
Copyright (C) 2002-20, Bruce Allen, Christian Franke, www.smartmontools.org

=== START OF INFORMATION SECTION ===
Device Model:     WDC WD10SDZW-11UMGS0
Serial Number:    WD-WXC1EA7AMPDV
LU WWN Device Id: 5 0014ee 6085a8435
Firmware Version: 01.01A01
User Capacity:    1,000,171,331,584 bytes [1.00 TB]
Sector Sizes:     512 bytes logical, 4096 bytes physical
Rotation Rate:    5400 rpm
Form Factor:      2.5 inches
TRIM Command:     Available, deterministic
Device is:        Not in smartctl database [for details use: -P showall]
ATA Version is:   ACS-3 T13/2161-D revision 5
SATA Version is:  SATA 3.1, 6.0 Gb/s (current: 6.0 Gb/s)
Local Time is:    Wed Jun  9 20:46:30 2021 +0430
SMART support is: Available - device has SMART capability.
SMART support is: Enabled

=== START OF READ SMART DATA SECTION ===
SMART overall-health self-assessment test result: PASSED

General SMART Values:
Offline data collection status:  (0x00) Offline data collection activity
                    was never started.
                    Auto Offline Data Collection: Disabled.
Self-test execution status:      ( 249) Self-test routine in progress...
                    90% of test remaining.
Total time to complete Offline 
data collection:        ( 5640) seconds.
Offline data collection
capabilities:            (0x51) SMART execute Offline immediate.
                    No Auto Offline data collection support.
                    Suspend Offline collection upon new
                    command.
                    No Offline surface scan supported.
                    Self-test supported.
                    No Conveyance Self-test supported.
                    Selective Self-test supported.
SMART capabilities:            (0x0003) Saves SMART data before entering
                    power-saving mode.
                    Supports SMART auto save timer.
Error logging capability:        (0x01) Error logging supported.
                    General Purpose Logging supported.
Short self-test routine 
recommended polling time:    (   2) minutes.
Extended self-test routine
recommended polling time:    ( 101) minutes.
SCT capabilities:          (0x7035) SCT Status supported.
                    SCT Feature Control supported.
                    SCT Data Table supported.

SMART Attributes Data Structure revision number: 16
Vendor Specific SMART Attributes with Thresholds:
ID# ATTRIBUTE_NAME          FLAG     VALUE WORST THRESH TYPE      UPDATED  WHEN_FAILED RAW_VALUE
  1 Raw_Read_Error_Rate     0x002f   200   200   051    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
  3 Spin_Up_Time            0x0027   162   154   021    Pre-fail  Always       -       2891
  4 Start_Stop_Count        0x0032   097   097   000    Old_age   Always       -       3222
  5 Reallocated_Sector_Ct   0x0033   200   200   140    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
  7 Seek_Error_Rate         0x002e   200   200   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
  9 Power_On_Hours          0x0032   088   088   000    Old_age   Always       -       8922
 10 Spin_Retry_Count        0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
 11 Calibration_Retry_Count 0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
 12 Power_Cycle_Count       0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       699
192 Power-Off_Retract_Count 0x0032   200   200   000    Old_age   Always       -       242
193 Load_Cycle_Count        0x0032   194   194   000    Old_age   Always       -       19269
194 Temperature_Celsius     0x0022   108   089   000    Old_age   Always       -       35
196 Reallocated_Event_Count 0x0032   200   200   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
197 Current_Pending_Sector  0x0032   200   200   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
198 Offline_Uncorrectable   0x0030   100   253   000    Old_age   Offline      -       0
199 UDMA_CRC_Error_Count    0x0032   200   200   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
200 Multi_Zone_Error_Rate   0x0008   100   253   000    Old_age   Offline      -       0

SMART Error Log Version: 1
No Errors Logged

SMART Self-test log structure revision number 1
No self-tests have been logged.  [To run self-tests, use: smartctl -t]

SMART Selective self-test log data structure revision number 1
 SPAN  MIN_LBA  MAX_LBA  CURRENT_TEST_STATUS
    1        0        0  Not_testing
    2        0        0  Not_testing
    3        0        0  Not_testing
    4        0        0  Not_testing
    5        0        0  Not_testing
Selective self-test flags (0x0):
  After scanning selected spans, do NOT read-scan remainder of disk.
If Selective self-test is pending on power-up, resume after 0 minute delay.
```

.

```
[~]$ sudo smartctl -a /dev/nvme0n1
smartctl 7.2 2021-01-17 r5171 [x86_64-linux-5.12.7-200.fc33.x86_64] (local build)
Copyright (C) 2002-20, Bruce Allen, Christian Franke, www.smartmontools.org

=== START OF INFORMATION SECTION ===
Model Number:                       KINGSTON RBUSNS8154P3256GJ3
Serial Number:                      50026B76837DFCA2
Firmware Version:                   E8FK11.T
PCI Vendor/Subsystem ID:            0x2646
IEEE OUI Identifier:                0x0026b7
Total NVM Capacity:                 256,060,514,304 [256 GB]
Unallocated NVM Capacity:           0
Controller ID:                      0
NVMe Version:                       1.2
Number of Namespaces:               1
Namespace 1 Size/Capacity:          256,060,514,304 [256 GB]
Namespace 1 Formatted LBA Size:     512
Namespace 1 IEEE EUI-64:            0026b7 6837dfca25
Local Time is:                      Wed Jun  9 20:46:36 2021 +0430
Firmware Updates (0x02):            1 Slot
Optional Admin Commands (0x0007):   Security Format Frmw_DL
Optional NVM Commands (0x001e):     Wr_Unc DS_Mngmt Wr_Zero Sav/Sel_Feat
Log Page Attributes (0x04):         Ext_Get_Lg
Maximum Data Transfer Size:         512 Pages
Warning  Comp. Temp. Threshold:     84 Celsius
Critical Comp. Temp. Threshold:     88 Celsius

Supported Power States
St Op     Max   Active     Idle   RL RT WL WT  Ent_Lat  Ex_Lat
 0 +     7.90W  0.0790W       -    0  0  0  0      600     600
 1 +     7.90W  0.0790W       -    0  0  0  0      600     600
 2 +     7.90W  0.0790W       -    0  0  0  0      600     600
 3 -   0.1000W  0.0790W       -    3  3  3  3     1000    1000
 4 -   0.0050W  0.0790W       -    4  4  4  4   400000   90000

Supported LBA Sizes (NSID 0x1)
Id Fmt  Data  Metadt  Rel_Perf
 0 +     512       0         1
 1 -    4096       0         0

=== START OF SMART DATA SECTION ===
SMART overall-health self-assessment test result: PASSED

SMART/Health Information (NVMe Log 0x02)
Critical Warning:                   0x00
Temperature:                        34 Celsius
Available Spare:                    100%
Available Spare Threshold:          10%
Percentage Used:                    2%
Data Units Read:                    9,993,626 [5.11 TB]
Data Units Written:                 9,423,808 [4.82 TB]
Host Read Commands:                 164,581,082
Host Write Commands:                147,886,816
Controller Busy Time:               631
Power Cycles:                       725
Power On Hours:                     3,129
Unsafe Shutdowns:                   26
Media and Data Integrity Errors:    0
Error Information Log Entries:      210
Warning  Comp. Temperature Time:    0
Critical Comp. Temperature Time:    0
Temperature Sensor 2:               34 Celsius

Error Information (NVMe Log 0x01, 16 of 16 entries)
Num   ErrCount  SQId   CmdId  Status  PELoc          LBA  NSID    VS
  0        210     0  0x002d  0x0203      -            0     0     -
  1        209     0  0x002c  0x0203      -            0     0     -
  2        208     0  0x001d  0x0203      -            0     0     -
  3        207     0  0x0002  0x0005      -          208     0     -
  4        206     0  0x002d  0x0203      -            0     0     -
  5        205     0  0x002c  0x0203      -            0     0     -
  6        204     0  0x001d  0x0203      -            0     0     -
  7        203     0  0x0002  0x0005      -          208     0     -
  8        202     0  0x002d  0x0203      -            0     0     -
  9        201     0  0x002c  0x0203      -            0     0     -
 10        200     0  0x001d  0x0203      -            0     0     -
 11        199     0  0x0002  0x0005      -          208     0     -
 12        198     0  0x002d  0x0203      -            0     0     -
 13        197     0  0x002c  0x0203      -            0     0     -
 14        196     0  0x001d  0x0203      -            0     0     -
 15        195     0  0x0002  0x0005      -          208     0     -
```

and here is heat sensors data:

```
[~]$ sensors
iwlwifi_1-virtual-0
Adapter: Virtual device
temp1:        +30.0°C  

asus-isa-0000
Adapter: ISA adapter
cpu_fan:     2300 RPM

nouveau-pci-0100
Adapter: PCI adapter
fan1:           0 RPM
temp1:        +42.0°C  (high = +95.0°C, hyst =  +3.0°C)
                       (crit = +105.0°C, hyst =  +5.0°C)
                       (emerg = +135.0°C, hyst =  +5.0°C)

BAT0-acpi-0
Adapter: ACPI interface
in0:          15.68 V  

coretemp-isa-0000
Adapter: ISA adapter
Package id 0:  +44.0°C  (high = +100.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 0:        +42.0°C  (high = +100.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 1:        +44.0°C  (high = +100.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 2:        +40.0°C  (high = +100.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 3:        +41.0°C  (high = +100.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 4:        +41.0°C  (high = +100.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 5:        +41.0°C  (high = +100.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)

pch_cannonlake-virtual-0
Adapter: Virtual device
temp1:        +48.0°C  

nvme-pci-0200
Adapter: PCI adapter
Composite:    +26.9°C  (low  = -40.1°C, high = +83.8°C)
                       (crit = +87.8°C)
Sensor 2:     +26.9°C  (low  = -40.1°C, high = +83.8°C)

acpitz-acpi-0
Adapter: ACPI interface
temp1:        +43.0°C  (crit = +103.0°C)
```

Comment: Please check drive's SMART data and include it here (use the [Edit] button)

Comment: To piggy-back on @gronostaj's comment, you'll need to also run a short and long [S.M.A.R.T test](https://superuser.com/a/1466640/529800) on Linux via `smartctl` _(CrystalDiskInfo in Windows will not provide the information required to determine if a drive is failing or has a hardware issue and there is no `smartctl` binary for Windows)_. The hard drive is the most likely issue, but if not, there's a hardware issue elsewhere if the issue occurs across different OSes _(incl. heat dissipation - check fans and heat sinks are clear of dust)_ - Run the BIOS/UEFI hardware diagnostic long tests

Comment: @gronostaj done

Comment: @JW0914 Actually there is a smartctl binary for Windows  Ive never used it but https://www.smartmontools.org/wiki/Download#InstalltheWindowspackage

Comment: @davidgo I just tried it and it works great; the only thing I haven't figured out yet is since they're still using Linux disc terminology [`smartctl --scan` will list all drives, but 
 as `sda`, `sdb`, etc.] is how to correlate that disk listing to the drives installed without manually issuing `smartctl -a /dev/sd*` for every drive.