# Why haven't boot errors show up after cleaning the dust?

Tags: hard-drive, freeze, hardware-failure

So my laptop freezes frequently, it's so slow, and there are some errors while booting. Errors are the following:

> Reboot and Select proper Boot device or Insert Boot Media in selected
> Boot device and press a key_

> A disk read error occurred
> Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Del</kbd> to restart

> Port O : HGST HTE721010A9E630
> S.M.A.R.T Statues Bad. Backup and Replace
> Press <kbd>F1</kbd> to resume

I know that the last message means my hard drive is failing. I bought a new computer and had some free time to open my previous laptop and clean the dusts. I disassembled all components. After I re-assembled things and turned on the computer, there was no boot error and windows was running more smoothly. It was like that for a month until I didn't used it for one or two weeks and everything is like the first right now, namely windows freezes and I get boot errors. My question is that why boot errors did not show up after I cleaned the dust?

Comment: Sometimes hardware just fails randomly. There's nothing more to this. Replace the drive and restore from backups.

Comment: The boot issues were coming from data corruption, likely due to the HDD's issue - use [`smartmontools`](https://www.smartmontools.org/wiki/Download) to view the drive's S.M.A.R.T data to determine what is the issue with it [`smartctl -a /dev/<disk>`] _(see [3.2](https://superuser.com/a/1466640/529800) and below, ignoring the Linux info [`sudo`])_; depending on what the S.M.A.R.T data shows, replacement may be required. It would also be recommended to run the BIOS/UEFI hardware diagnostics to rule out any other hardware issues.

Comment: @gronostaj Without knowing specifically what S.M.A.R.T values are out of range, or whether hardware issues are listed, replacing the drive without reviewing the S.M.A.R.T data via `smartmontools` [`smartctl -a /dev/disk`] would be unwise.

Comment: @JW0914 Yes, on a second thought that could also be a connection issue. That would explain why it was fixed for a while (wiggling/reseating the cable). The BIOS may have noticed that error count stopped increasing and cancelled the warnings.